# Filter through array of strings and return to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the array of strings and i need to filter this array due to the input value.  I filter it through filter function, but when i clear input the array stays filtered. How get an initial array?

```
filterCoins = (e) => {
        let updatedList = this.state.data;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
            return item.toLowerCase().search(
                e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        this.setState({data: updatedList});
    };
```

Comment: looks like you are modifying original array.

Comment: Where do you keep the original list, the one before any filtering?

Comment: Original array is in state

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on how you're getting the initial data.

If it's from `props`, better have it into `state` for populating `filteredList`.

```
updatedList = this.props.data.filter(function(item){
    return item.toLowerCase().search(
        e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});
```

If it's self contained state component, then use class variable `this.data` to store initial data filter the searched item from `this.data`;

```
updatedList = this.data.filter(function(item){
    return item.toLowerCase().search(
        e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});
this.setState({data: updatedList});
```

So the suggestion is always filter from the original list.

Comment: i am getting from state

Comment: If that's the case maintain two variables like `data` to store original and `filteredData` to searched content.

Answer (score 0):

The original `data` is currently being replaced in state whenever the input value is changed. 
This means you either need to keep the old data around in state so that you can revert back to it when input is cleared or come upon another way to do the implementation.

I would set the input value in state in place of updating data when the input value changes.

```
setCoinFilter = (e) => {
    this.setState({ filterText: e.target.value });
}
```

Then in the component rendering the items; the filter operation can be performed.

```
state = {
  data: [],
  filterText: '',
}

filterCoins(coins, filterText) {
  return coins.filter(function(coin) {
    return coin.toLowerCase(filterText.toLowerCase()).search() !== -1;
  });
}

shouldNotApplyFilter() {
   const { filterText } = this.state;
   return filterText === null || filterText === '';
}

render() {
   const data = this.shouldNotApplyFilter() ? this.state.data :
     filterCoins(this.state.data, this.state.filterText) 
    // render data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when your input is cleared, `e.target.value` will be empty, then you need to reset `this.state.data` to its original value. I assumed the original value is kept in the state, so you can write the `filtercoins` function like this

```
filterCoins = (e) => {
    let newData;

    if (e.target.value) {
       newData = this.state.data.filter(item =>
           item.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       );   
    } else {
       newData = this.state.originalData;
    }

    this.setState({data: newData});
};
```